# GraphQl resolver not returning null from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am working on a side project of making a news aggregator app with node js, express, MongoDB, and graphql. it's a graphql API that returns data from the MongoDB database which I am having issues with.

**Server.js file**

```
const Parser = require("rss-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
const Schema = require("./Schema");
const extractor = require("unfluff");
const axios = require("axios");
const queries = require("./graphql/queries");

//instantiation of parser
const parser = new Parser();
const app = express();

//mongodb connection to atlas cloud
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/feeds", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

//log on db connection
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("open", () => {
  console.log("Db connected");
});

//rss receiver and parser
const rssNews = async () => {
  //rss query
  let feed = await parser.parseURL("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml#");

  //items array in rss
  let items = await feed.items;

  //looping through news articles and saving to MongoDb
  items.map((item) => {
    let title = item.title;
    let link = item.link;
    let description = item.contentSnippet;
    let date = item.isoDate;

    //getting the html content of each link and extracting image and content ou of it.
    axios.get(link).then((res) => {
      const data = extractor(res.data);

      let content = data.text;
      let imgLink = data.image;

      const record = new Schema.news({
        title,
        link,
        description,
        date,
        source: "BBC",
        content,
        imgLink,
      });

      //checking if the link exists or not and saving to db if not
      Schema.news.findOne({ link }).exec(function (err, result) {
        if (result === null) {
          record.save(() => {
            console.log("Record saved");
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

const rssTech = async () => {
  //rss query
  let feed = await parser.parseURL("https://www.cnet.com/rss/news/");

  //items array in rss
  let items = await feed.items;

  //looping through news articles and saving to MongoDb
  items.map((item) => {
    let title = item.title;
    let link = item.link;
    let description = item.contentSnippet;
    let date = item.pubDate;

    //getting the html content of each link and extracting image and content ou of it.
    axios.get(link).then((res) => {
      const data = extractor(res.data);

      let content = data.text;
      let imgLink = data.image;

      const record = new Schema.tech({
        title: title.replace(/- CNET/, ""),
        link,
        description,
        date,
        source: "CNET",
        content,
        imgLink,
      });

      //checking if the link exists or not and saving to db if not
      Schema.tech.findOne({ link }).exec(function (err, result) {
        if (result === null) {
          record.save(() => {
            console.log("Record saved");
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

const rssSports = async () => {
  //rss query
  let feed = await parser.parseURL("https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/news");

  //items array in rss
  let items = await feed.items;

  //looping through news articles and saving to MongoDb
  items.map((item) => {
    let title = item.title;
    let link = item.link;
    let description = item.description;
    let date = item.pubDate;

    //getting the html content of each link and extracting image and content ou of it.
    axios.get(link).then((res) => {
      const data = extractor(res.data);

      let content = data.text;
      let imgLink = data.image;

      const record = new Schema.sports({
        title,
        link,
        description,
        date,
        source: "ESPN",
        content,
        imgLink,
      });

      //checking if the link exists or not and saving to db if not
      Schema.sports.findOne({ link }).exec(function (err, result) {
        if (result === null) {
          record.save(() => {
            console.log("Record saved");
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

const rssBusiness = async () => {
  //rss query
  let feed = await parser.parseURL(
    "https://www.cnbc.com/id/10001147/device/rss/rss.html"
  );

  //items array in rss
  let items = await feed.items;

  //looping through news articles and saving to MongoDb
  items.map((item) => {
    let title = item.title;
    let link = item.link;
    let description = item.description;
    let date = item.pubDate;

    //getting the html content of each link and extracting image and content ou of it.
    axios.get(link).then((res) => {
      const data = extractor(res.data);

      let content = data.text;
      let imgLink = data.image;

      const record = new Schema.business({
        title,
        link,
        description,
        date,
        source: "CNBC",
        content,
        imgLink,
      });

      //checking if the link exists or not and saving to db if not
      Schema.business.findOne({ link }).exec(function (err, result) {
        if (result === null) {
          record.save(() => {
            console.log("Record saved");
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
};

//update rss feed
rssBusiness();
rssTech();
rssNews();
rssSports();

//graphql api setup
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: queries,
    graphiql: true,
  })
);

//listening app on port 5000
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server started...");
});
```

And Here's the graphql query file that return null when I request data from it:

```
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLID,
} = graphql;
const resolvers = require("./resolvers");
const isoDate = require("graphql-iso-date");
const { GraphQLDateTime } = isoDate;
const Schema = require("../Schema");
const FeedType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "feed",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
    link: { type: GraphQLString },
    date: { type: GraphQLDateTime },
    source: { type: GraphQLString },
    content: { type: GraphQLString },
    imgLink: { type: GraphQLString },
  }),
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    news: {
      type: FeedType,
      args: { limit: { type: GraphQLInt } },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Schema.news.find({});
      },
    },

    tech: {
      type: FeedType,
      args: { limit: { type: GraphQLInt } },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Schema.tech.find({});
      },
    },
    sports: {
      type: FeedType,
      args: { limit: { type: GraphQLInt } },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Schema.sports.find({});
      },
    },
    business: {
      type: FeedType,
      args: { limit: { type: GraphQLInt } },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return Schema.business.find({});
      },
    },
  },
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery,
});
```

And my mongodb schema file if you need:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  description: String,
  date: Date,
  source: String,
  content: String,
  imgLink: String,
});

module.exports = {
  news: mongoose.model("news", schema),
  tech: mongoose.model("tech", schema),
  sports: mongoose.model("sports", schema),
  business: mongoose.model("business", schema),
};
```

Comment: Thanks for including all the relevant code. However, it's not clear from your question what the exact issue is. If you're seeing an error, please include the full error message in your post. If you're encountering some unexpected behavior, please explain in detail both the expected behavior and the actual behavior you're seeing.

Comment: OK I resolved the Issue!